# Add background image to bottom of flex div

Tags: html, css

I am trying to add a bottom background to a Flex `div` so that it becomes like this:

[image]

The bottom background is the following cut:

[image]

However the bottom background is not showing.

```css
.group {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  width: 100%;
}

.block {
  flex: 25%;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  .block {
    flex: 50%;
  }
}

.main, .block {
  display: flex;
  flex-grow: 1;
}

.main {
  padding: 10px;
}

.text {
  flex-grow: 1;
  background-color: green; 
  padding: 10px;
}

.text::after {
  background: transparent url("https://i.stack.imgur.com/qN0S5.png") no-repeat center bottom / 100% auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="group">
    <div class="block">
        <div class="main">
            <div class="text">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="block">
        <div class="main">
            <div class="text">Lorem ipsum.</div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="block">
        <div class="main">
            <div class="text">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="block">
        <div class="main">
            <div class="text">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

How to to this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `position`, `content`, `padding-top`, `margin-bottom`.

it's too wordy to explain you can ask me what i don't understand

```css
.group {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  width: 100%;
}

.block {
  flex: 25%;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  .block {
    flex: 50%;
  }
}

.main, .block {
  display: flex;
  flex-grow: 1;
}

.main {
  padding: 10px;
}

.text {
  flex-grow: 1;
  background-color: green; 
  padding: 10px;
  /* add */
  position: relative;
  margin-bottom: 18.83408071748879%;
  /* /add */

}

.text::after {
  /* add */
  content: "";
  width: 100%;
  padding-top: 18.83408071748879%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 100%;
  left: 0;
  /* /add */
  background: transparent url("https://i.stack.imgur.com/qN0S5.png") no-repeat center bottom / 100% auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="group">
    <div class="block">
        <div class="main">
            <div class="text">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="block">
        <div class="main">
            <div class="text">Lorem ipsum.</div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="block">
        <div class="main">
            <div class="text">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="block">
        <div class="main">
            <div class="text">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: How did you calculate the value 18.83408071748879%;? Thank you.

Comment: @MiguelMoura let's get `image height` / `image width`  * `100%`

Answer (score -1):

You forgot to add position and content for after and .text:after must have height and width to display your background image.

You can check code below.

There is another way using clip-path for more visit link https://css-tricks.com/exploring-the-css-paint-api-rounding-shapes/

```css
.group {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  width: 100%;
}

.block {
  flex: 25%;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  .block {
    flex: 50%;
  }
}

.main, .block {
  display: flex;
  flex-grow: 1;
}

.main {
  padding: 10px;
}

.text {
  flex-grow: 1;
  background-color: green; 
  padding: 10px;
  position:relative;
}

.text::after {
  width:100%;
  content:'';
  left:0;
  height:35px;
  bottom:-25px;
  position:absolute;
  background: transparent url("https://i.stack.imgur.com/qN0S5.png") no-repeat center bottom / 100% auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="group">
    <div class="block">
        <div class="main">
            <div class="text">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="block">
        <div class="main">
            <div class="text">Lorem ipsum.</div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="block">
        <div class="main">
            <div class="text">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="block">
        <div class="main">
            <div class="text">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Your solution is not working when resizing the window. The bottom background image moves out of place

Comment: I tried to use Clip Path, and used it before, but wasn't able to define that Curve in Clip-Path. Is there a easy way to define that curve for Clip Path and use it responsive?